# How to export summary and detail drill through SSRS report in one excel on 2 different tabs

Tags: excel, reporting-services, drillthrough

I have 2 SSRS reports. One is Summary (Main) report and other is Detail report. Summary report has Drill Through functionality which opens Detail report. I want to export both reports in one Excel file on 2 different tabs. I came across with [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a520d4de-f21a-4b57-932d-2f86d519edaa/drillthrough-reports-as-separate-tabs-when-exported-to-excel?forum=sqlreportingservices) solution but it's hard to understand.

Comment: In the solution you linked, the user added the detail table to the main report. He then set the visibility on the detail so it only appears when the report is exported. `=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCELOPENXML" OR Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", false, true)` Make sure your table is set to have a page break and a page name for the separate tab. He doesn't filter the data as you might when using a drill through.

Comment: @HannoverFist  it’s working! thank you!